# Fazer regex JSON excluindo elemento

Tags: json, regex

Tenho o Json abaixo e preciso pegar apenas o retorno de token:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.zV5senq3QxOj3ds5dcbj8xMcaOVG1_ynCFVx2wgKICU"
}
```

Se eu aplicar a regex: `([A-Z_.0-9a-z])\w+` eu consigo recuperar, porém vem token junto, consigo excluir token literalmente?

Estou testando aqui: https://regexr.com/4el37

Comment: Eu só consigo usar regex, estou fazendo isso no Zabbix, ele só permiti o Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a palavra "token" tem 5 letras, você pode indicar na regex para começar a casar somente se o assunto tiver 6 ou mais caracteres.

A regex ficou assim: `([A-Z_.0-9a-z-]){6,}`

E [aqui](https://regexr.com/4el5u) você pode ver a regex em ação.